# Highcharter doesn't show Custom Colors in Reprex R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

When you want to add custom colors to a `highcharter` plot, you could modify your data beforehand to show each bar for example a custom color. This seems to work when doing in your RStudio console, but this doesn't work in a `reprex`. Here is a reproducible `reprex`:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
#> Highcharts (www.highcharts.com) is a Highsoft software product which is
#> not free for commercial and Governmental use

df <- data.frame(category = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
                n = c(2, 4, 5, 6))
cols <- c("#BC3C29FF", "#0072B5FF", "#E18727FF", "#20854EFF")

df %>% 
  mutate(colors = cols) %>%
  hchart(type = 'bar', hcaes(x = category, y = n, color = cols)) %>%
  hc_title(text = 'No colors in reprex')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see the custom colors are not shown in the plot. If you run the code just via your console it returns the following desired output:

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone knows why this doesn't work in the `reprex`?